# In linux Mint, directories won't show the blue colors

Tags: linux-mint, ls, colors, filezilla

I'm using FileZilla to create directories and for some reason, the directories are not showing as the default color blue in Linux. first time it showed but second time it did not[image: bad][image: good]

Comment: Same command in each case? `ls --color=auto` or something aliased to that?  If so, what does `ls -l` say, on both the directory that does work and the one that doesn't?

Comment: I used the same command ls -R to show the directories. I no longer have the working directorie. when I put the command, I get the directories without blue color.

Comment: Does your _home directory_ work? What do you see with `type -a ls`? `ls` does not (and IMHO should not) use color by default, so if you don't have an overriding alias, this is expected behavior

Comment: What commands did you use in the first and second case? In what environment (e.g. how did you open the terminal, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to explain how to alias `ls` with the --color flag, but this answer has everything you need to know: https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/630945

If you are using a CLI app to list dirs, you may need to configure it separately to always use colored output (if it isn't using bash for example). Try `man [app name]`.

Also, make sure your console profile is configured correctly. In `konsole` or `gnome-terminal` open the Edit menu and navigate to the Appearance tab.